# Construct QuerySet that returns a list of the five objects with highest IntegerField values in the database

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am following the official Django tutorial and creating a polling website.  I have the following models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    questionText = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField('published date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questionText

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choiceText = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choiceText
```

I would like the homepage to display the top 5 most voted on questions, but am struggling to construct the proper `QuerySet` to get this result. The only thing I have thought of doing is:

```
def index(request):
   questions = Question.objects.order_by(*question.choice_set.votes*) 
   #I left *question.choice_set.votes* like that because I'm not sure how to properly express that in code or if it is possible in this example
```

Also, would it be better to give the `Question` class a method like `returnMostVotedOn(numberOfQuestions)` or is using a `QuerySet` the correct method? Thanks in advance.

*If anyone can think of a better question title feel free to change it, I was struggling to briefly define my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate each question with a sum of total votes and then order by that annotated field. You can slice a queryset to get the first n results

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Question.objects.annotate(
    total_votes=Sum('choice__votes')
).order_by('-total_votes')[:5]
```

Comment: This queryset returns the 5 questions with the highest total number of votes cast. Not sure where you're getting that it returns answers

Answer (score 0):

I would do this. It will store all the users who vote on a particular question in a many to many field, and then just count how many users are in the 'votes' field and slice the list off at 5.

modals

```
class Question(models.Model):
    questionText = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField('published date')
    votes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questionText

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choiceText = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

views

```
from django.db.models import Count    
obj = Question.objects.annotate(q_count=Count('votes')).order_by('-q_count')[:5]
```